# How to find if a number is a subset of a given integer in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program with python to find if a number is present as a set in another number

for example:
if the number, `a = '123456789010234`
and I have to find if `'4567'` is present in a or not.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `in`, if both are integers:

```
str(num) in str(a)
```

---

```
>>> a = 123456789010234
>>> num = 4567
>>> str(num) in str(a)
True
```

Comment: @GlenVeigas no problem!

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
if '4567' in a:
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is a `string` you can just do this:

```py
a = '123456789010234'
value = '4567'

if value in a:
    print(f'Value {value} present in {a}')
else:
    print(f'Value {value} not present in {a}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
if '123456789010234'.find('4567') > 0: 
     print ("Found!") 
  else: 
     print("Not Found!") 

#Found!

if '123456789010234'.find('4d567') > 0: 
     print ("Found!") 
else: 
      print("Not Found!") 

#Not Found!
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are receiving both the numbers as strings:

```
a = '123456789010234'
b = '4567'
print(True if b in a else False)
```

If you are receiving as `int`s, convert to string and check with `in` operator.

If you need to check whether the strings are integer at all, or need to handle negative integers, you need to use `try-except`.